# I2S based Codec

Tags: audio, amplifier, i2s

I want to drive a small mono-speaker that helps in announcing few messages. I am just learning and doing it now. My board is based on I.MX6, I am interfacing it to a an audio codec TLV320AIC32 via I2S.

My queries are:

1. DIN of processor should be connected to  DIN of CODEC (slave) or DOUT of  CODEC? Likewise for DOUT line as well.
2. If I will have to drive a 1W mono speaker, what needs to be taken care regarding drive capability (amplifier connections) and audio signals connectivity? Let me know about the calculations to be done.
3. What is bridge terminated load (BTL)? What difference does it bring to connectivity part?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet regarding the connections is to take a look at some reference design. FSL provides e.g. the SABRE reference design for its i.MX6 family.

Go to [i.MX Design Tools](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX6Q&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab) and select Printed Circuit Boards and Schematics-Schematics (3) -> i.MX6_SABRE_AI_DESIGNFILES. I should contain all the info you need.

For the analog questions, probably someone else has a nice answer. I would just make sure to be able to get the heat from the amplifier stage away and to have a solid analog ground connection.